# Will the EFI Developer Kit 2 create .efi files from Intel syntax assembly code?

Tags: assembly

I am trying to build EDK2 because I think it will create .efi files from Intel syntax assembly code, but I am having a lot of trouble so I just wanted verification that EDK2 does that before I spend more hours trying to build it.

If it can't do that, is there some software (preferably free) that can do that?

If you need more clarification, I want some software that could cross-assemble code from Linux to a UEFI computer.

EDIT: Thanks, @Steve Barnes. Does EDK2 cross-assemble *UEFI* assembly??

Comment: As far as I know you are going to be out of luck because Intel ASM specifically targets __Intel__ processors while UEFI is cross processor so you need to be writing in C, or UEFI ASM, rather than Intel ASM.

Answer (score 1):

After tons of research, I figured out that a .efi file is just a portable executable. FASM can do portable executables.